# PHP: how to use errors within if statements

Tags: php, error-handling, ldap

I want to use the error_log function for LDAP Bind. However, I'm not sure how to call error_log in this situation:

```
if ($bind = ldap($ds, $un, $pw) {
  print("match");
} else {
  print("no match");
}
```

I'm aware I can use

```
if ($bind = ldap() or die) {
```

but that only prints the error on screen. I want to log it into a file if the LDAP server is unreachable.

Comment: Do you want the script to halt at that situation or to continue in case of such failure?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-log.php

Put this into your else statements.

Answer (score 0):

The error_log function is really simple to use, you can do something like this:

```
 error_log("A custom error has been triggered",  1, "someone@example.com", "From: webmaster@example.com");
```

So in your case you can have:

```
if ($bind = ldap($ds, $un, $pw) {
  print("match");
} else {
  print("no match");
  error_log("No match", 1);
}
```

You can handle the path of the error log from php.ini. For example, it will be something like this:

```
 error_log = /tmp/php_errors.log
```

For more you can see the official documentation at: https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-log.php

As for the LDAP error , you just need to use the function ldap_error: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ldap-error.php

Comment: This works, however, if the user who logs in supplies the wrong password, the log file will be written to. All I care to know is if LDAP failed to respond for some other reason.

Comment: I did update my response at the bottom. If you at least think that my answer is useful please add one reputation to the answer.